# Inherited a class from EventDispatcher in Flash but custom event not received

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a custom event that is dispatched when a slider is moved but I receive no event from inherited dispatcher class I created whereas I followed the same syntax as solution for  [My flash custom event doesn't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582398/my-flash-custom-event-doesnt-trigger)

Event class:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;

     public class CustomEvent extends Event
     {
            public static const ON_DISPATCHER_EVENT = "onDispatcherEvent";
        public var value:Number;

        public function CustomEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false):void
        {
           super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

     }

}
```

Dispatcher:

```
package {

    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class CustomEventDispatcher extends EventDispatcher {

        private var cEvent: CustomEvent;      

        public function CustomEventDispatcher() {

        }

        public function raiseEvent(_value:Number) {
            cEvent = new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.ON_DISPATCHER_EVENT);
            cEvent.value = _value;
            dispatchEvent(cEvent);                      
        }

    }
}
```

Test class:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.events.SliderEvent;
    import fl.controls.Slider;

    public class TestCustomEvent extends MovieClip {        

      private var cEvent: CustomEvent;

      public function TestCustomEvent() {   

        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);  

      }

      public function init( e:Event ):void {

        removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );

        this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.ON_DISPATCHER_EVENT,OnDispatcherEvent);

        slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,OnSliderEventChange);

      } 


      public function OnDispatcherEvent(event:CustomEvent): void {

            trace(event.value);
      }


      public function OnSliderEventChange(event:SliderEvent) {

            cEvent = new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.ON_DISPATCHER_EVENT);
            cEvent.value = event.value;
            dispatchEvent(cEvent);
                    trace("hello");

      }

    }       
}
```

Comment: Although not the answer to your problem, there are a few things I've noticed: 1) you've made all your methods publicly accessible, which is something you probably want to avoid, especially where your event handlers are concerned; 2) you've named your event handlers in your `TestCustomEvent` class with capital letters at the start, generally in AS3 you name your methods via camelCase with the constructor method being the only exception.

Comment: 3) Although merely an example, you may want to rename the public static constant in your `CustomEvent` class from `ON_DISPATCHER_EVENT` to `CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE` for two reasons, one, the public static constant represents the "custom event type" and two, "on dispatcher event" is a name better suited to an event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your understanding of the event flow is a bit off. The answer I already gave in [My flash custom event doesn't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582398/my-flash-custom-event-doesnt-trigger) (that I'm assuming you didn't read) I think is the proper way to use custom `Event` and `IEventDispatcher` objects:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _sliderSprite:SliderSprite;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _sliderSprite = new SliderSprite();
            _sliderSprite.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
            _sliderSprite.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
            addChild(_sliderSprite);

        }// end function
    }// end class

}// end package

import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class SliderSprite extends Sprite
{
    private var _slider:Slider;

    public function SliderSprite()
    {
        init();

    }// end function

    private function init():void
    {
        _slider = new Slider();
        addChild(_slider);

        _slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSliderChange);
        addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onSliderSpriteCustomEventType);

    }// end function

    private function onSliderSpriteCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
    {
        trace(e.value);

    }// end function

    private function onSliderChange(e:SliderEvent):void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, e.value));

    }// end function

}// end class

import flash.events.Event;

internal class CustomEvent extends Event
{
    public static const CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE:String = "customEventType";
    private var _value:Number;

    public function get value():Number
    {
        return _value;

    }// end function

    public function CustomEvent(type:String, 
                                value:Number,
                                bubbles:Boolean = false,
                                cancelable:Boolean = false)
    {
        _value = value;

        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

    }// end function

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new CustomEvent(type, value, bubbles, cancelable);

    }// end function

}// end class
```

**[UPDATE]** 
***[EDITED 08/04/2011 08:22]***

I've modified the code to encapsulate all code involving dispatching and listening to/for  events, as well as excuting event handlers, into another class(`EventDispatcherManager`).

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

internal class SliderSprite extends Sprite
{
    private var _slider:Slider;
    private var _eventDispatcherManager:EventDispatcherManager;

    public function SliderSprite()
    {
        init();

    }// end function

    private function init():void
    {
        _slider = new Slider();
        addChild(_slider);

        _eventDispatcherManager = new EventDispatcherManager(IEventDispatcher(_slider));

    }// end function

}// end class

import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

internal class EventDispatcherManager extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function EventDispatcherManager(slider:IEventDispatcher)
    {
        slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSliderChange);
        this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);

    }// end function

    private function onSliderChange(e:SliderEvent):void
    {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, e.value));

    }// end function

    private function onCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
    {
        trace(e.value);

    }// end function

}// end function
```

Comment: In the other quesstion someone gave the exact cause for it not working. Now this cause doesn't seem to be the same. I'm looking at your code and as I'm beginner it's not easy for me to understand. As I read adobe help EventDispatcher fits my need I'd like to know how to use it

Comment: I will try your code but please help me with EventDispatcher also cause I don't like not to understand what seems basics in help file.

Comment: I want to dispatch event from a class that is not inheriting from sprite or movieclip so as I understood I must inherit from EventDispatcher ?

Comment: By help with "'EventDispatcher'", do you mean help with  your "'CustomEventDispatcher'" class in your question's code sample? If so, what was the purpose of it? and by that I mean, what did you want it to do?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you want to do, let me update my answer.

Comment: I don't think so: I want to dispatch an event from ANOTHER class than the sprite or movieclip that is a pure class with no GUI.

Comment: Hmm, if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to encapsulate(hide) all the code involving dispatching and listening to events in another class, something like an event dispatcher manager? If so, I've edited the updated portion of my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: Great that works !!! I wonder why mine doesn't but should be able to find out by comparing with yours.

Comment: Using your code I now don't understand why I don't receive the event in main http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599588/why-i-do-only-receive-custom-event-in-eventdispatcher-and-not-in-main

Comment: To be honest you shouldn't use the 'EventDispatcherManager' in the first place, it will only make things more confusing and its generally bad practice. Use the original code instead and also read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384294/how-to-pass-variables-in-actionscript/4394875#4394875 it explains custom events.

Answer (score 0):

Is hello being traced?

It looks like maybe there is a vague reference as to which dispatcher is calling the  `disptachEvent()` method. Try specifying `slider.dispatchEvent()` and use `slider.addEventListener()` to listen for your custom event.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be importing CustomEventDispatcher class in your test file

Comment: @user310291 what I think Saad means is that 'CustomEventDispatcher` isn't utilized at any point in the application. @Saad your answer seems better suited as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

event.value doesn't exist
try tracing event alone and see what you get
Pretty sure you need something like event.target.value

Comment: "value" is a public variable in the CustomEvent subclass. "event.target" would be the object that dispatched the event, not the event itself.

Comment: I down-voted your answer because it contained incorrect information. That's, like, the point of down-votes.

Comment: @The_asMan well jHocking's choice to down vote you is justified as your statement "event.value doesn't exist" is incorrect. If you were simply suggesting he "try something", you could have just as easily added a comment to this question with your suggestion rather than adding an answer that is incorrect. Don't take it personally, the purpose of a down vote is to highlight an answer that is incorrect (among other things wrong) as it can mislead others who may think its correct and go on the rest of their lives believing false information.

Comment: Now I don't understand why you say event.value doesn't exist since I created public var value:Number; in CustomEvent class ?

Comment: @Taurayi hope you understand nunya

Comment: @user310291 it was simply a simple mistake on The_asMan's part @The_asMan I understand nunya, but you need to understand when your wrong and when to simply admit it. Also I wasn't trying to be be rude with my previous comment, just logical, as to answer your question "you down voted me for asking him to try something?"

Comment: geez if I knew this was going to become a big deal I wouldn't have bothered. Now of course you get a net positive rep because of the up-vote so you can just delete this answer.