# Why I do only receive custom event in EventDispatcher and not in main?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I dispatch a custom event from an event dispatcher (following solution [Inherited a class from EventDispatcher in Flash but custom event not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586830/inherited-a-class-from-eventdispatcher-in-flash-but-custom-event-not-received)) and I add a listener in both dispatcher itself and in main. trace shows that only dispatcher receives this event not main. How to make main also receive the event ?

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _sliderSprite:SliderSprite;

        public function main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _sliderSprite = new SliderSprite();
            _sliderSprite.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
            _sliderSprite.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
            addChild(_sliderSprite);
            this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);

        }// end function

        private function onCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
        {
                    // never triggered
            trace("hello");

        }// end function

    }// end class


}// end package
```

class 2

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import fl.controls.Slider;

    public class SliderSprite extends Sprite
    {
        private var _slider:Slider;
        private var _eventDispatcherManager:EventDispatcherManager;

        public function SliderSprite()
        {
            init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void
        {
            _slider = new Slider();
            addChild(_slider);

            _eventDispatcherManager = new EventDispatcherManager(IEventDispatcher(_slider));

        }// end function

    }// end class

}
```

class 3

```
package {

import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.events.*;

internal class EventDispatcherManager extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function EventDispatcherManager(slider:IEventDispatcher)
    {
        slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSliderChange);
        this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);

    }// end function

    private function onSliderChange(e:SliderEvent):void
    {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, e.value));

    }// end function

    private function onCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
    {
        // triggered
        trace(e.value);

    }// end function

}// end function

}
```

class 4

```
package  {
import flash.events.Event;

internal class CustomEvent extends Event
{
    public static const CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE:String = "customEventType";
    private var _value:Number;

    public function get value():Number
    {
        return _value;

    }// end function

    public function CustomEvent(type:String, 
                                value:Number,
                                bubbles:Boolean = false,
                                cancelable:Boolean = false)
    {
        _value = value;

        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

    }// end function

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new CustomEvent(type, value, bubbles, cancelable);

    }// end function

}// end class

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your instance of the main class to recieve events from the EventDispatcherManager, you have to register main as a listener with the EventDispatcherManager.

Something like:

```
//in main:
sliderSprite.eventDispatcherManager.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE,onCustomEvent);
```

But for that to work you would have to either set the _eventDispatcherManager propterty as public och make it accessible through an accessor, or a simple get-function.

Though I would strongly recommend you to look over the structure. By the look of it you could skip the EventDispatcherManager class and the CustomEvent class, and just dispath the value directly from the SliderEvent to Main.

But this is maybe just a Demo example?

Edit:

This is what a getter function would look like:

```
function get eventDispatcherManager():EventDispatcherManager {
       return _eventDispatcherManager;
}
```

Put that function in your SliderSprite class and call it from Main just as I described above.

Comment: I think he is simply trying to grasp the concept of event dispatching and custom events. I think I made the subject more confusing by showing him how to encapsulate the logic for dispatching events, listening for events and calling event handlers. I should have mentioned it is not a good practice.

Comment: Can you also mention(and show an example) in your answer that he would also have to make the `_eventDispatcherManager` object publicly accessible, preferably with a getter method. That way I can up vote your answer and suggest that it should be the accepted answer for this question(I know its already implied that you would make it publicly accessible, but its for the sake of making this answer the best that it can be).

Comment: you could skip the EventDispatcherManager class and the CustomEvent class, and just dispath the value directly from the SliderEvent to Main: that I have done already, I want now to have a separate class that dispatch FROM it to GUI.

Comment: I don't understand why I cannot just add simply a listener like I did in Dispatcher, why Adobe makes things more complicated than it should be ?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it is not Adobe that is complicating it. You just haven't grasped the concept yet. But don't worry, you will. In Dispatcher you registered the listening function to this, since it is the Dispatcher class that is dispatching the Event to itself. But in Main you can't register to this, since you don't want Main to make the dispatch, but the Dispatcher.

Comment: Is there any way I can do so by getting the parent which instantiates the slider ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604384/why-flash-doesnt-recognize-this-parent-property-how-to-get-the-parent-which-in

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [event phases](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_07.html) in ActionScript 3.
If shortly, your EventDispatcherManager is not DisplayObject and is not on display list. That's why, your custom event doesn't bubble and doesn't reach your main.

Comment: And so what can I do to bubble it to main ?

Comment: I don't find this response helpful at all. Events can be made to bubble up the display chain, and that makes perfect sense for somethng like a mouse click, but that is not what you want because your EventDispatcherManager is not a DisplayObject and it wouldn't make any sense to me to make it one. Tjofras's response has what you are after.. you need to register your listeners with your EventDispatcherManager instance.