# Is it impossible with Flash to get the Instance Creator?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to add a listener to the parent of a slider which is receiving the event from a non-gui class the EventDispatcherManager. So I tried to get the parent of the slider which should return the main class but it doesn't work. How to get the object (here main class) which instantiates an other (here a slider class) ?

```
package {

import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.events.*;

internal class EventDispatcherManager extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function EventDispatcherManager(slider:IEventDispatcher)
    {
        slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSliderChange);

        // 1119: Access of possibly undefined property parent through a reference with static type flash.events:IEventDispatcher.
        slider.parent.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);

        this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);

    }// end function

    private function onSliderChange(e:SliderEvent):void
    {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, e.value));

    }// end function

    private function onCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
    {
        trace(e.value);

    }// end function

}// end function

}


package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _sliderSprite:SliderSprite;
        private var _eventDispatcherManager:EventDispatcherManager;

        public function main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _sliderSprite = new SliderSprite();
            _sliderSprite.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
            _sliderSprite.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
            addChild(_sliderSprite);

        }// end function

        private function onCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
        {
            trace("hello");

        }// end function

    }// end class


}// end package


package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import fl.controls.Slider;

    public class SliderSprite extends Sprite
    {
        private var _slider:Slider;
        private var _eventDispatcherManager:EventDispatcherManager;

        public function SliderSprite()
        {
            init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void
        {
            _slider = new Slider();
            addChild(_slider);

            _eventDispatcherManager = new EventDispatcherManager(IEventDispatcher(_slider));

        }// end function

    }// end class

}


package  {

import flash.events.Event;

internal class CustomEvent extends Event {

    public static const CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE:String = "customEventType";

    private var _value:Number;

    public function get value():Number
    {
        return _value;

    }// end function

    public function CustomEvent(type:String, 
                                value:Number,
                                bubbles:Boolean = false,
                                cancelable:Boolean = false)
    {
        _value = value;

        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

    }// end function

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new CustomEvent(type, value, bubbles, cancelable);

    }// end function

}// end class

}
```

Update: now I did cast to DisplayObject and use .parent.parent since the slider is within another class sliderSprite but now I get null! So Is it impossible with Flash to get the Instance Creator ?

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.events.*;

internal class EventDispatcherManager extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function EventDispatcherManager(slider:IEventDispatcher)
    {
        slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSliderChange);

        // 1119: Access of possibly undefined property parent through a reference with static type flash.events:IEventDispatcher.
        (slider as DisplayObject).parent.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);
        trace((slider as DisplayObject).parent.parent);
        this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);

    }// end function

    private function onSliderChange(e:SliderEvent):void
    {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, e.value));

    }// end function

    private function onCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
    {
        trace(e.value);

    }// end function

}// end function

}
```

Comment: it's not recognized either because maybe it's not on the stage yet That's why I need to reference the INSTANCE CREATOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of your constructor implies `slider` is an `IEventDispatcher` and nothing else. The property `parent` doesn't exist on this interface. You have to specify another type in the constructor (such as `DisplayObject`).

Comment: Also, if the display object is not in the display list, parent property is null.

Comment: That's right, but in that case the slider is already added as a child to a `Sprite`.

Comment: can't I do so by casting slider to DisplayObject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604761/flash-how-can-i-cast-a-slider-class-to-displayobject-in-flash

Comment: What do you mean :) also can you look at my update parent.parent returns null instead of main class as I would like

Comment: @OXMO456 that's why I said above I need to reference the INSTANCE CREATOR not to the display stage that contains the VISUAL object since it isn't added yet.

Comment: Your SliderSprite is not added to anything when you create the `EventDispatcherManager`. You should only call its init on an onAddedToStage listener. Check a few things by yourself before pavlovianly asking here ;)

Comment: Well I don't know Flash so I tried to do like I would do in other language :) OK I'll look at onAddedToStage which I never used before.

Comment: Still my question is general : can't I get the instance creator whatever the context ?

Comment: `parent` doesn't return the "creator" but the parent, which is the element that called `addChild`. If you try to read `parent` before an element has been added to anything, it will fail.

Comment: And to complete this answer, if you don't pass the "creator" (which is the class in which you called `new`) via the constructor of your child class, no, there isn't any possibility to retrieve this "creator".

Comment: ok thanks that's what I wanted to be sure though I would have hoped flash could have done for creator like what he does for parent !