# Flash: how can I cast a slider class to DisplayObject in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I tried this:

```
    (DisplayObject(slider)).parent.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);
```

but flash doesn't like

For whole context see
[Is it impossible with Flash to get the Instance Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604384/why-flash-doesnt-recognize-this-parent-property-how-to-get-the-parent-which-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(slider as DisplayObject).parent.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onCustomEventType);
```