# How to redispatch a custom event to another class (not a parent) in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I cannot bubble the event because I want to send to another class that is not even a movieclip but a simple class.

So I transform previous source code here
[Is it impossible with Flash to get the Instance Creator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604384/is-it-impossible-with-flash-to-get-the-instance-creator) for

```
private function onCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
{
    trace(e.value);
    //redispatch
    this.dispatchEvent(e as CustomEvent);

}// end function
```

error is

> conversion of flash.events to CustomEvent impossible

Whereas I have casted to CustomEvent to be sure!

Comment: Show us the code, where you dispatch your event and the code of CustomEvent class. And you shouldn't do this casting (e as CustomEvent).

Comment: see my update for source code thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your event handler you can dispatch the event again. But what happens then is that Flash Player clones the event that was received into a new one. When you have made your own custom events, you should therefore always override the clone() function. Otherwise you will get runtime errors such as the one you mentioned.

in your case your CustomEvent class should have this method

```
    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new CustomEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
```

and if your constructor needs additional parameters make sure to put them in there too.

Comment: OK thanks what I did is to create a new event but will try the clone now :)

Answer (score 1):

The bubbling of events does not occur in the object that is receiving the event, but in the object that make the dispatch. Or to be precise, the event is bubbling through all the ancestors of the dispatching object. So you don't have to worry about that.

And also, you are already receiving a `CustomEvent` in your `onCustomEventType`-function, so there is no need to cast it.

Comment: yes but in my case the bubbling is not possible: the target is not in hierarchy of dispatcher object.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you be more specific on what the problem is?

Comment: I just want to know in general how to resend a custom event received by one object to another whatever the other object is or where it is.